# Deserialize from tokio socket

Tags: asynchronous, rust, serde, rust-tokio

I am using tokio to implement a server which communicates with messages serialized with serde (bincode). Without asynchronous and futures I would do

```
extern crate tokio_io;
extern crate bincode;
extern crate serde;
extern crate bytes;
extern crate futures;
#[macro_use] extern crate serde_derive;

use tokio_io::{AsyncRead, AsyncWrite};
use tokio_io::io::{read_exact, write_all};
use bincode::{serialize, deserialize, deserialize_from, Infinite, serialized_size};
use std::io::Read;
use std::io::Cursor;
use futures::future::Future;

type Item = String; // Dummy, this is a complex struct with derived Serizalize
type Error = bincode::Error;

// This works
fn decode<R>(reader: &mut R) -> Result<Item, Error> where R: Read {
    let message: Item = deserialize_from(reader, Infinite)?;
    Ok(message)
}

fn main() {

    let ser = serialize("Test", Infinite).unwrap();
    let buf = Cursor::new(ser);

    let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(buf);

    println!("{:?}", decode(&mut reader))
}
```

But what I need is a `decode` function which can work with an asyncronous socket as

```
// I need this since I get the reader from a (tokio) socket as
// let socket = TcpListener::bind(&addr, &handle).unwrap();
// let (reader, writer) = socket.split();
fn decode_async<R>(reader: R) -> Result<Item, Error> where R: AsyncRead {
    // Does not work:   
    let message: Item = deserialize_from(reader, Infinite)?;
    Ok(message)
}
```

The only idea I have is to manually write the length into the buffer during encoding and then use read_exact:

```
// Encode with size
fn encode_async(item: &Item) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Error>{
    let size = serialized_size(item);
    let mut buf = serialize(&size, Infinite).unwrap();
    let ser = serialize(item, Infinite).unwrap();
    buf.extend(ser);
    Ok(buf)
}

// Decode with size
fn decode_async<R>(reader: R) -> Box<Future<Item = Item, Error = std::io::Error>>
    where R: AsyncRead + 'static {

    let read = read_exact(reader, vec![0u8; 8]).and_then(|(reader, buf)| {
        let size = deserialize::<u64>(&mut &buf[..]).unwrap();
        Ok((reader, size as usize))
    }).and_then(|(reader, size)| {
        read_exact(reader, vec![0u8; size])
    }).and_then(|(reader, buf)| {
        let item = deserialize(&mut &buf[..]).unwrap();
        Ok(item)
    });

    Box::new(read)
}

fn main() {

    let ser = encode_async(&String::from("Test")).unwrap();
    let buf = Cursor::new(ser);

    let mut reader = std::io::BufReader::new(buf);
    let dec = decode_async(reader).wait();

    println!("{:?}", dec)
}
```

Is there a better way to implement the decoding?

Answer (score 4):

[`deserialize_from`](https://docs.rs/bincode/0.9.2/bincode/fn.deserialize_from.html) can't handle IO errors, especially not of the kind [`WouldBlock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html#variant.WouldBlock) which is returned by async (non-blocking) `Read`ers when they are waiting for more data.  That is limited by the interface: `deserialize_from` doesn't return a `Future` or a partial state, it returns the full decoded `Result` and wouldn't know how to combine the `Read`er with an event loop to handle `WouldBlock` without busy looping.

Theoretically, it is possible to implement an `async_deserialize_from`, but not by using the interfaces provided by `serde` unless you read the full data to decode in advance, which would defeat the purpose.

You need to read the full data using [`tokio_io::io::read_to_end`](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.4/tokio_io/io/fn.read_to_end.html) or [`tokio_io::io::read_exact`](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.4/tokio_io/io/fn.read_exact.html) (what you're currently using), if you know the size of the encoded data in an "endless" stream (or in a stream followed by other data).

Answer (score 0):

Stefan's answer is correct, however you might be interested in looking at the tokio-serde-* family of crates which do this for you, specifically [tokio-serde-bincode](https://crates.io/crates/tokio-serde-bincode). From the readme:

> Utilities needed to easily implement a Tokio Bincode transport using serde for serialization and deserialization of frame values. Based on tokio-serde.

The crate has several [examples](https://github.com/luben/tokio-serde-bincode/tree/master/examples) of how to use it.